# Aliens like giant grasshoppers invade earth, give black people power over whites

Tags: story-identification, novel, alien-invasion

I'm looking for a novel that I think was published before 2006; it was a great read.

From what I can remember there was an aggressor alien species that came to earth and put the human race into something like castes to control them. They gave black people power and made whites more like slaves. This alien race were like giant grasshoppers or bugs and could jump high.

There was another friendly alien race that befriended humans; they were very short and might have been a slave race. Humans taught them military tactics and tech, and both these friendly aliens and humans were able to defeat their mutual enemy.

Answer (score 15):

### *Deathday*

This is *DeathDay* by William Dietz. Its sequel is *EarthRise*.

[image]

The most notable detail is confirmed by [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PersecutionFlip):

> In the Deathday and Earthrise duology, Earth is invaded by an alien race known as the Saurons. The Saurons have a Fantastic Caste System based on scale color: black-scaled Saurons (Zin) are the ruling class, brown-scaled (Kan) are the soldiers, and white-scaled (Fon) are the laborers. When the Saurons enslave humanity, they treat darker-skinned humans much better than white-skinned humans as a result, which sets the stage for racial strife among the humans even as they try to overthrow the Saurons.

Amazon [notes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01EXCI4K8) the Saurons' insectoid appearance:

> The huge, insect-like Saurons, nicknamed "chits" for their chitinous shells, kill billions.

As for the other species, I quote [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/42897/51379):

> The next closest example I can think of is William Dietz’s DeathDay/EarthRise duology (2001) which chronicles the invasion of Earth by Saurons aided by the Ra ‘Na, who are a slave race to the Saurons (the ‘pets’ are actively involved in the invasion, rather than being brought in later).